# IComparable sorting with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I had a similar question answered earlier, then my boss told me to sort it based on date so here I am again.
I have this -

```
    List<User> users;
    protected class User : IComparable<User>
    {
    public string name;
    public string email;
    public decimal total;
    public string address;
    public string company;
    public string placed;
    public string fulfilled;
    public string origin;
    public int CompareTo(User b)
    {
        // Alphabetic sort name[A to Z]
        return this.placed.CompareTo(b.placed);

    }
}
```

My datetime format is MM/DD/YYYY, so it goes by the month, not by the whole thing. What's the best way to get it to sort based on the full date? Thanks!

Comment: What is the date field?

Comment: Sorry, "placed" is the date field. As in the date it was placed.

Comment: I recommend having DateTime parse the date into a DateTime object.

Comment: Why is your date field not a DateTime?  If it were DateTime, it would sort properly.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924435(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: There is no `DateTime` in you post. Please clarify what you have problem with - parsing your text into date time, changing type to have `DateTime` field or comparing two `DateTime` values with `<` operator.

Comment: Honestly, I don't do this sort of programming. I'm pretty much strictly design, didn't even know making it a DateTime object was a thing. Regardless, I got it working. Thanks everyone, I'd upvote you all if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know it is a date, then why store it as `string`? use dedicated `DateTime` type. It will work as expected.

If you can't change the field to `DateTime` for some reason, you can always do the following

```
public int CompareTo(User b)
{
    DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(this.placed,...);
    DateTime y = DateTime.ParseExact(b.placed,...);
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```